# How to add spaces to a string in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, string, split

I am new to VBA and trying to populate a MsgBox that says "Congratulations" and references 2 other cells to get the person's first and last name into the message box. I have the following code written which comes out as one word:

First_Place_Winner = "Congratulations" + Cells(2, 6) + Cells(2, 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concat spaces between the values

`First_Place_Winner = "Congratulations " + Cells(2, 6) + " " + Cells(2, 7)`